# Android String-arrays create Item with Id

Tags: android

How to create Like this select List in android XML file:

```
<select id="..t" name="...">
   <option value="1">Excellent</option>
   <option value="2">Good</option>
   <option value="3">Average</option>
   <option value="4">Bad</option>
   <option value="5">Very Bad</option>
</select>
```

Is this code valid ?

```
<string-array name="...">
    <item value="10">Excellent</item>
    <item value="8">good</item>
    <item value="5">Average</item>
    ....
</string-array>
```

If it's valid how to get the value of selected item in java code ?

Comment: Since array indexes always range from 0 to n-1 (n = item count), you can't use **indexes as values**, if these values are "custom". But you might use a parallel array and connect the values to the descriptions by using a common index.

Comment: Sorry but I've just get started with android can you explain more how to do this ? Also The value are stored in my database and web app so how can I handel this ? and create the same item with same value like the web app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since array indexes always range from 0 to n-1 (n = item count), and you can only define one-dimensional vectors in resources, you can't use indexes as values.
At least, not if these values are meant to represent "custom" values.

But you might use a parallel array and connect the values to the descriptions by using a common index.

This is pretty much similar to how ListPreferences work:

```
android:entries="@array/prefs_send_titles"
android:entryValues="@array/prefs_send_values"
```

You have 2 distinct arrays in your resources: one for the descriptions and one for the values.

---

To get a value from the selected item, declare an integer to hold the value:

```
int value = 0;
```

The use the aforementioned `switch ... case`:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected
(
    AdapterView<?> parent,View view, int position, long id
)
{
    int pos = mySpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();

    switch (pos)
    {
    case 0:
        value = 5;
        break;
    case 1:
        value = 8;
        break;
    case 2:
        value = 11;
        break;
    }
}
```

Or you can use the values from an array. I don't show this technique, since it 
would be longer to write, but it's intuitive.

---

To set the Spinner to the desired description basing on the corresponding value (put this in your initialization routine):

```
    try
    {
        int pos = 0;
        switch(value)
        {
            case 5:
                pos = 0;
                break;
            case 8:
                pos = 1;
                break;
            case 11:
                pos = 2;
                break;
        }
        mySpinner.setSelection(pos);
    }
    catch(final Exception e)
    {
        mySpinner.setSelection(0);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry but I've just get started with android can you explain more how to do this ? Also The value are stored in my database and web app so how can I handel this ? and create the same item with same value like the web app

Comment: I see. You retrieve the numbers from the Web and store them in the db. So you don't have a way to associate the value to indexes. You can do that in code. Maybe using a `switch` to determine which string to retrieve basing on the value.

Comment: That means for each Spinner I have to create an array for item to diplays `android:entries` and an array for value of each item `android:entryValues` and Those array has to be in ordred way?

Comment: I have an APi that get data from the web then those data i need to be show as spinner (selected item)

Comment: Not exactly. For Spinners there's only one array. The item order gives the indexes. As I sugegsted, you can use a switch to associate an index to a value - or vice-versa, for the opposite operation - return a value from a Spinner or show the Spinner selected item from a value.

Comment: A useful reading on Spinners: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64260/discussion-between-chlebta-and-funkystein).

Comment: In case you do't know how to handle data with a `switch case`: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/switch-statement/java-switch-case-example/

Comment: I know how to use switch case, this will work for some spinner (static spinner where thier content is not updated) but for other spinner, dynamic one where i get data from my server then i show it in the spinner, it will not work. can we discuss that on chat

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the method, I dont think the value="" is valid inside a resource array.

```
String[] arrayRes = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.*name of array*)
```

You can just call getResources in an activity, but anything else you will need to call it from a context object.

Comment: How does this post answer the OP question?

Comment: Well, i thought OP meant the value of the arrays items, I guess he did mean that value="" value. He would just need to use parallel arrays as you commented. One with values, and one with <items>.